# Ubuntu Grub restore (12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center, windows-7, grubrescue

I reinstalled Windows 7, but I lost the grub loader.

Is there anyway I can access my Ubuntu partition again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue before, and one of my F keys allowed me to get into the boot loader for Windows 7. That boot loader had a record of Ubuntu existing on the system. It was either F4 or F8, I can't remember.

Comment: I tried F4, and the windows boot loader showed up, with only windows 7 listed.

Comment: Strange. It kept a record for Ubuntu when I had this issue. Since that's the case, though.. I would boot into Windows 7 and follow [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022), and then try to use the Windows boot loader again. Looking for a guide like that for Windows 7, but only found XP so far.

Comment: You may actually be better off using [this](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). I haven't used Windows in a while, so I'm not up to date with all of the ins and outs of their new boot loader. Apparently `Boot.ini` doesn't even exist since Windows Vista.

Comment: Thanks, but my windows corrupted my entire system...I just had to reinstall everything...thanks anyways

Comment: That sucks. Sorry to hear that. Glad you got it fixed in the end, though.